# Setting X-Frame-Options in PHP

Tags: php

How can I set X-Frame-Options in my PHP code so that it will be there in all the web pages from my server. Basically, I am trying to avoid iframe loading of my web app.

Comment: Did you search on stackoverflow like the helpdesk more or less [requires](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?? Something like [PHP prevent iframe loading](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=PHP+prevent+iframe+loading) or [PHP  X-Frame-Options](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=PHP++X-Frame-Options) as i am pretty sure this question could be marked as a duplicate..

Comment: ... also the [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options#Browser_compatibility) off `X-Frame-Options` is not very wide..

Comment: Thanks for input @ Raymond Nijland. Could you please suggest alternatives for compatibility for all browsers ?

Comment: In the [Content-Security-Policy](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Content_Security_Policy) standard, there is also a policy to pervent iframe/object tag loading..  But jet again only of the browser supports it..   for a bit more backup compatibility you also most likely want to use a bit of javascript to break out that iframe but still javascript could be turned off..

Comment: [owasp](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet.html) has good information about this.. There they call it Clickjacking as this method is mostly done with a hidden iframe on top of something to do something under water.. Like a youtube/facebook vote you never knew you did..

Comment: It will really helpful if you can share a code snippet. Do you mean to add as header? I didn't get the javascript code to be used in iframe.

Comment: see mine last comment..

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use below in your php file which outputs response to client side.

```
header("X-Frame-Options: DENY");
```

DENY will fully block. You may try SAMEORIGIN option also.

```
header("X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN");
```

If you are using apache web server, you can directly set in httpd.conf also.

```
<Directory />
    ...
    Header always set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 2):

The X-Frame-Options prevents your site content embedded into other sites. Browser allowed other sites to open web page in iframe. It also secure your Apache web server from clickjacking attack.

**There are three options available to set with X-Frame-Options:**

‘**SAMEORIGIN**’ – With this setting, you can embed pages on same origin. For example, add iframe of a page to site itself.

‘**ALLOW-FROM uri** – Use this setting to allow specific origin (website/domain) to embed pages of your site in iframe.

‘**DENY** – This will not allow any website to embed your site pages in an iframe.

We have two way to Setup X-Frame-Options

**1. with Apache Configuration**

**2.  with .htaccess**

with Apache configuration:

> Debian based systems: /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/security.conf
> Redhat based systems: /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
Header set X-Frame-Options: "SAMEORIGIN"  #Allow for Same Origin (Default Action)
Header set X-Frame-Options: "ALLOW-FROM http://example.com/" #Allow from specific origin
Header set X-Frame-Options: "DENY" #Deny to everyone
```

with .htaccess

```
Header append X-Frame-Options: "SAMEORIGIN"
```

Answer (score 0):

My message is a long shot, but I gave found this thread while looking for this issue.

Turns out, WordPress offers you (and recommends!) a nice way to do this using the [Redirection plugin](https://wordpress.com/plugins/redirection). You can check the Wordpress documentation [here](https://wordpress.com/support/add-http-headers/).

The only gotcha is that you need a Creator or Entrepreneur plan to use it :x