# set X-Frame-Options Header in Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

morning, I want to add X-Frame-Options Header sameorigin in codeigniter, how can I do that?
I tried adding this code in .htaccess but it didn't work

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It's not a Codeigniter issue.
I successfully added this header by adding `Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN` to site's configuration (depends on webserver [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options)).
For Apache and Ubuntu it will be in /etc/apache2/sites-available/YOUR_CONF_NAME.conf

Answer (score 0):

It is not something related to CI's configuration.It is about web servver .

We have two ways for Setuping X-Frame-Options

**1. with Apache Configuration**

**2. with .htaccess**

[there is completed answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58788696/setting-x-frame-options-in-php/69039639#69039639)